# union of connected compenent and connected subspace of x

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have to show that a connected component of a locally connected topological space is open. So I know for all $x$ in $X$ there exits a open neighbourhood $V$ being a subset of an open subset $U$ of $X$ s.t. $V$ is connected. I defined $C(x)$ to be the connected component of $x$. The hint said to consider $C(x)$ union $V$ which is connected. It further says that $C(x)=$ to the union.

Why does this happen. Is it because of the equivalence relation of $C(x)$. So since the set of the union is defined to be all points in common to both sets then the equivalence relation grants that the union is equal to $C(x)$ since it is the largest set containing $x$.

Does this imply $C(x)$ is open because $V$ is open?

Does this answer the question or is it asking if the connected component of the topological space $X$ is open?

If so would I just consider the union of the $C(x_j)$ for all $x_j$'s in $X$. Then this would be open since each $C(x_j)$ is open by the above argument and union of open is open?

Comment: How have you defined $C(x)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You are to show that if $C$ is a connected component of the locally connected space $X$, then $C$ is an open set in $X$. One way to show this is to show that if $x\in C$, then there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq C$. So let $x\in C$; clearly $C(x)=C$, and we know that $x$ has a connected open nbhd $V$. The hint suggests that you consider the set $C\cup V$.

- $C\cup V$ is connected; why?
- It follows that $C\subseteq C\cup V$; why?
- And from that it follows that $x\in V\subseteq C$; again, what are the details here?